# floating point conversion issue in SSAS dimension

Tags: floating-point, ssas, dimension

i have a issue with SSAS dimension. I have a column with a float datatype in a table. Values in this column are like

- 0
- 0.0001
- 0.0002
- 0.0003
- 0.0004

but when i created a dimension on this column in SSAS it converts floating values in scientific notation like (btw not all but some values are converted)

- 0
- 0.0001
- 2.000000000000001E-4
- 2.999999999999997E-4
- 4.000000000000002E-4

can someone please tell me how to fix this issue

Answer (score 2):

That is just the way that SSAS represents floats.  The value is not wrong, just not how you want to read it.

If you want to view as a decimal, try changing the input datatype (in your view prior to ssas) to decimal i.e.

```
SELECT      Id, CAST(floatValue AS decimal(10, 6)) AS decimalValue 
FROM        YourTable
```

That way, SSAS will pesist the decimal to a fixed number of decimals and show 0.000200, not 2.000000000000001E-4